# Is it ok to call execute method of batch more than once

Tags: apex, batch

I have an object with fields 'Message', 'Call_Out_To', 'Status'. After 15 successful record inserts into this object, trigger is fired and batch job is called. Within the batch execute method, I have like this

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Obj__c> scope){

   for(Obj__c c : scope){
      if(c.Call_Out_To__c == 'webservice_CM'){
         //post the message on this record to webserive_cm
      }
      if(c.Call_Out_To__c == 'webservice_DC'){
         //post the message on this record to webserive_dc
      }
      if(c.Call_Out_To__c == 'webservice_CD'){
         //post the message on this record to webserive_cd
      }
   }
}
```

After the trigger is fired, execute of same batch is called more than once. I am not getting any error and it is working perfectly. But when I write test class, I get exception: " No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation" Also, would like to confirm if it is ok to call execute method more than once with in same batch ?

Test Method:

```
@isTest
static void testUnassignedCases(){
    CaseTriggerPostHandler cP = new CaseTriggerPostHandler();
    UtlityTest testHandler = new UtlityTest();
    List<case> cList = testHandler.createMultiCaseRec(con, u, a, 100);
    Map<Id, Case> oldMap = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, type, due_date__c, status, ownerId From Case Where Id In :cList]);
    List<Case> cList1 = cList;
    for(Case c : cList1){
        c.ownerId = g.id;
    }
    update cList1;
    Map<Id, Case> newMap = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, type, due_date__c, status, ownerId From Case Where Id In :cList1]);
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExternalSystemCalloutMockImpl('COMMON'));
    cP.CaseUpdate(cList1, oldMap, newMap);
    Test.stopTest();
    system.assertEquals(100, cP.f.unassignedCases.size());           
    system.assertEquals(0, cP.f.userCases.size());
    system.assertEquals(100, cP.f.queueCases.size());
    system.assertEquals(0, cP.f.unassignedCases1.size());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How and why is your trigger calling the batch method more than once? Post that as well as your test method too.

Comment: Trigger calling batch only once. For example, after 3 record inserts with call out to CM, DC, CD, trigger calls batch once and sends all these 3 records. In the execute method, all the 3 if conditions are true and hence same method is executed 3 times

Comment: That seems fine. Posting your test method will help.

Comment: added test method

Comment: You are doing update to case twice I think.. One when your are updating cList1 and probably in CaseUpdate method as well. This is causing the batch to fire twice I believe.

Comment: If 100 in `createMultiCaseRec(con, u, a, 100)` is lower than 90,  Iam not getting that error. But if more than or around 90, I am getting the error mentioned.

Comment: Difficult to say anything without seeing what that method does. But most likely your problem is because of multiple trigger invocations.

Comment: Will check again and let you know Aslam. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger might be calling the batch only once in that context. Each invocation of the trigger is a separate invocation, and a different context.

As for your test method you probably are trying to cover all the branches in your execute with just one method.

Instead write different test methods for different branches, so that each executes the batch only once.

**EDIT**

Seeing the test method the issue seems to be the multiple updates on Cases that might be invoking the batch more than once.

Comment: Aslam,  I found the solution... The issue is coming because, I declared batch size of 90. Till 90, it is one batch and no error. Above 90, more than one batch. I believe in test methods, we can execute only one batch. Does this sound correct for you ?

Comment: Yes correct. In the same test method you can execute a batch only once.  So I suppose the value of 90 should fix your problem